# What is it called if a vector space doesn't have an additive inverse?

Tags: fields, linear-algebra

so, you have, for any two members of the algebraic structure A and B and any nonnegative real values a, b:

two operations: * and +, such that

a*A + b*A = (a+b)*A is in the structure

A + B = B + A is in the structure

0*A + B = B

but there is no guarantee that X s.t.

X + A = B

is in the structure.

---

As an example, the set of 2-dimensional Cartesian vectors that are in the first quadrant (i.e., x>=0 and y>=0) has the properties that I want.  You can add them, scale them, but if you try to subtract them, you might leave the first quadrant.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't appropriate for MathOverflow.

Comment: I don't think you can have fully specified what you want. Early in your question you make no mention of division or real numbers but later you say that monoids lack division by non-negative real numbers.

Comment: I tried to fix things-- maybe vector spaces are the closer analogy.

Comment: Why is this not appropriate for MathOverflow?

Comment: oh, and regarding division by real numbers, they are implied since if a*A forall nonnegative a is in the structure, so is (1/a)*A.

Comment: I apologize, I misread your question and thought it was asking something a bit silly about real numbers. I suppose I might call this a "a commutative monoid over the monoid of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ under addition$, though I doubt that is a standard term, if there is one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the structure in question is a subset of a vector space, like it is in your example, I would call it a [convex cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone).

Answer (score 11):

I believe it is called a [module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29#Generalizations) over a [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).  In your example, the semiring is commutative.

Comment: Thank you!  So, I would just call it a "module over a commutative semiring"?

Comment: Yes.  Alternatively, you could say it is a module over the commutative semiring of nonnegative real numbers.